# In this what is the purpose of newfunction?

Tags: function, c++11, pointers, iterator, find

In this what is the purpose of newfunction?
Why don't its existence makes any change ?
Can anyone help me out please ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
bool newfunction (int m, int n)
{
  return (m==n);
}
int main ()
{
  int newints[] = {1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5};
  std::vector<int> haystack (newints,newints+10);
  int patt1[] = {1,2,3};
  std::vector<int>::iterator ti;
  ti = std::find_end (haystack.begin(), haystack.end(), patt1, patt1+3);
  if (ti!=haystack.end())
  std::cout << "patt1 last found at position " << (ti-haystack.begin()) << '\n';
  int patt2[] = {4,5,1};
  ti = std::find_end (haystack.begin(), haystack.end(), patt2, patt2+3, newfunction);
  if (ti!=haystack.end())
  std::cout << "patt2 last found at position " << (ti-haystack.begin()) << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: In this example, there's no point to `newfunction`. If the comparator argument is omitted, `std::find_end` uses `==` operator to compare elements. `newfunction` does the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`newFunction` serves as a comparison function here. As Igor mentioned, the argument `newFunction` can be omitted for the call to `std::find_end` and nothing will change. Thus, the purpose of `newFunction` here in this case is useless.

However, if you decided to have a different ordering than the operator `==` and/or additional logic like

```
bool newfunction (int m, int n)
{
  // for some reason you want to do this
  int m_rem = m % 5;
  int n_rem = n % 3;
  return (m_rem > n_rem);
}
```

the new ordering/logic will be performed instead of the default `==` in `std::find_end`.

I found a post that has some more information about comparison function/ comparator. Take a look at 2. in this [post](http://fusharblog.com/3-ways-to-define-comparison-functions-in-cpp/). Hope this helps!